# How do you get the execution context of a failed Firebase Function from its logs?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am using Firebase Functions triggers on top of Firestore documents.
If I define a function like this:

```
exports.myDocCreate = functions.firestore.document('docs/{docId}').onCreate(async (snap, context) => { 
  ///... code here
});
```

and it fails for whatever reason outside the code inside it (like scalability), would I be able to tell what the `context` was somewhere in the logs?

Inside the function code I handle errors and log details of what failed to know where to look after, but when it fails outside my control, I am lost and have no idea what the context is and what components of my code, data, or workflows were affected :(

Comment: Hi does my posted answer solves your issue ?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think so :(

Comment: Hi edited the answer with the infrastructure side of errors .If that does not help contact firebase support as your case requires project inspections.

Answer (score 0):

When the Firebase functions trigger fails, Firebase logs the error messages and stack traces in the Firebase console. You can find these logs in your firebase functions console tab by clicking on the 3 vertical dots button and selecting view logs.

In the logs, you will see the details of the error, including the context of the trigger that caused the error. This will include the ID of the document that triggered the function, and any other relevant data that was passed to the function.

Here’s one example of how it will logs the `context.eventId` and `context.resource` :

```
function[us-central1-myDocCreate]
{
 "severity": "INFO",
 "message": "Context EventId: bc8bb0c4-7b90-4391-a99b-5fc28ae14cf8"
}

function[us-central1-myDocCreate]
{
 "service": "firestore.googleapis.com",
 "name": "projects/<project-id>/databases/(default)/documents/users/EAj372JWiCKFpz17O9CL",
 "severity": "INFO",
 "message": "Context Resource:"
}
```

By going through the error message and stack trace, you can determine the root cause of the error and take steps to address it. If the error is related to scalability, you may need to consider optimizing your function code or upgrading the [functions memory](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#set_timeout_and_memory_allocation) to support higher traffic volumes.

**Update**:
When a function fails due to an infrastructure issue, Firebase will log the error as an "Uncaught Exception." The error message will contain information about the context of the function, including the function name and the document ID that triggered the function.

```
Ex: Error: 8 RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED: Quota exceeded for quota metric 'Function invocations' and limit 'Function invocations per minute' of service 'cloudfunctions.googleapis.com' for consumer 'project_number:123456789'. Function invocation was throttled. Function: 'myDocCreate'.  Document ID: 'abc123'.
```

You can test these scenarios with [firebase emulators](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite) where you can see the logs in the firebase emulator suite,Emulator is kind of a testing environment which runs locally, so that your workflows will not be affected.

Comment: thank you. that is the place I started to look at and can't see anything like that.. from firebase functions after clicking the ellipsis it jumps me into GCP Log Explorer. There I do not seem to have any context or any IDs that look similar to my firestore documents.  See image below. 
and yes this is "outside my code" type of error. so that is what I am trying to investigate. it could be any type of infrastructure error and at least would like to know what was affected when it did not run ...

https://i.ibb.co/wptgp18/GCP-Func-Error.jpg

Comment: @GeneRator "outside my code" means what type of error are you looking for ? that Log Explorer has all the stack traces of function life and if you want to see context then you can write `functions.logger.log("Context:", context);` log to get that. Also take a look at [these docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/writing-and-viewing-logs) about Write and view logs

Comment: the function fails before it reaches my code. so adding logs or any type of code does not help here. like I said this is a 500 error from the infrastructure (most likely scalability and it was not able to spin up or scale new instanced and it failed). so what I was wondering if there is a way to know the context when this fails, so I know what code did not run against what data.

Comment: Hi edited the answer with infrastructure side of errors .If that does not help contact [firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support) as your case requires project inspections.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't see any document ID anywhere in my logs wen it fails due to infrastructure.. FWIW, the error I get is `The request was aborted because there was no available instance`. and yes thank you, I have reached out to firebase support